# construct triangles in Poincare disc

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

The wiki page 
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré_disk_model#cite_note-MSE1333850-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#cite_note-MSE1333850-3)
shows a famous image titled "the (6,4,2) triangular hyperbolic tiling".
From another entry, it reads "triangular tiles whose vertices have angles $\pi/2,\pi/4,\pi/6$". I guess one angle corresponds to an arc in the disc.

However, I cannot find the right formula that maps an angle $\theta_1$ to an arc (represented as an equation evolving $x,y$, such as $x^2+y^2=1$) in the Poincare disc.
Help! thanks!

Comment: Maybe you are confusing spherical geometry  with hyperbolic geometry

but for hyperbolic geometry you can find some formulas at wikipedia hyperbolic triangle general trigonometry ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle#General_trigonometry )

Comment: @Willemien,thanks, I got it and programmed it.